# Custom Button with Background color

Tags: android, button, custom-component

I want to create four custom buttons(As Roundedrects in iOS) on the top of the screen.

Using the Custom xml with shape tag , I can get it .

Custom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#F9FAFC" />
<corners android:radius = "20dp"/>
</shape>
```

I am using it as:

```
android:background = "@drawable/custom"
```

But I am getting only the color(grey) set as in the custom xml for all the buttons, which shouldn't.

I want to set different Hexa(#FF0000 ... ) colors to that custom buttons.After lot of research on this site, I think it will be better to rise a question.

Any of you geeks can point the link or please help me with some code , how to achieve above requirement.

**PLEASE NOTE: I don't need three states of the button as Pressed, Focused, Disabled. I already have four buttons with Square Shape. Now I want to create them as Rounded Rect shape to make it look Attractively.As for the case I can't create 4 CUSTOM files in drawable folder for 4 BUTTONS. Because in future my requirement may extend to some 8-10 buttons or even more .***

Thank you.

Comment: if u want create four different button with different colors create 4 different xml with its own color code

Comment: Are you sure?  I mean if I have 10 buttons or more , Will you suggest this? Is there no other way??

Comment: if you want to have 10 buttons each with its own color and shape then you have to. But I am not sure you can wait till u get answers from others

Answer (score 1):

you need to use item tags. here is an example containing button states, solid and gradient colors, strokes, paddings and corner radius. you need to put this into selector tags.

```
<item android:state_enabled="false" >
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#474141" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#474141" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#f3ae1b" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#f3ae1b" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#990000"
            android:endColor="#990000"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#990000" />
        <corners
            android:radius="4dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```